# windows app in java using eclipse

Tags: java, database, eclipse

I want to write a fairly basic database application to run in Windows (not console) using the Eclipse IDE.  I have been googling most of the day and my head is spinning having downloaded GWT, SDKs, Tomcat and heaven knows what else.  I am still confused and have yet to find a basic step by step tutorial that does not leave me hanging in the air.  I hope someone else has gone through this process and found a useful tutorial.

Comment: Can you tell more about the specifics of where you're stuck? Your question is very broad, too broad (in my mind) to be answerable just  yet.

Comment: Maybe you don't need Tomcat,instead you need a mysql server.

Comment: One of the first questions is, are you building a desktop application (something that runs as a Windows program, or a browser-based application (where the client runs in the browser)? These days, most new applications are browser-based, so I recommend that.

Comment: As mentioned, you need to define what you're actually trying to do. GWT is a web framework. Swing or SWT are desktop GUI frameworks. Tomcat is for webapps only; if you're doing a webapp, you may want to make it an embedded app. I disagree with @FrancisUpton that a desktop app should be browser-based, although it's certainly a possibility--whether or not it's appropriate depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

When I first started to develop a visual application in Java that would query a database, I bought the book Swing Hacks. It has a good example of how to query a database and load it to a jtable. I think the link I'm pasting below has enough to get you started and it has some example code.

Here's a link to that section of the book with the source code they use.

[Swing Hacks, Loading data from a database](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/swinghks_hack24/index.html?page=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop a simple DB application, then you don't really need GWT. You don't need Tomcat either. I would start by downloading the Eclipse IDE, and MySQL. Once you have these installed you may want to come back and ask more specific questions if you run into difficulties.

Some links that may help you here, I just googled 'database application eclipse'.

[link1](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-EclipseDbWebapps/index.html)
[link2](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-EclipseDbWebapps/2006-04-10/article.html)